# Understanding put_record documentation for boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, base64, boto3, amazon-kinesis-firehose

The official documentation of Boto3 for kinesis forehouse is : [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/firehose.html#Firehose.Client.put_record)

The put_record method writes a single record to firehose stream. It says in the put_record documentation that:

> "The data blob, which is base64-encoded when the blob is serialized. The maximum size of the data blob, before base64-encoding, is 1,000 KiB"

What is the meaning of these lines? Can we pass any data into put_record or do we need to base64 encode it ourselves first? Can someone please help here.

Also there is b literal there. Does this mean that the data we pass is automatically converted into bytes or we need to supply a byte array there?

Comment: Did you try sending byte array? Did it work?

Comment: No i dont have any access to aws resources.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve, in that case?

Comment: im trying to understand the meaning of : "The data blob, which is base64-encoded when the blob is serialized. The maximum size of the data blob, before base64-encoding, is 1,000 KiB"

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, the AWS SDKs base64-encode the data that you send them ([example](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-data-generator/issues/5)), so you send a byte array, boto3 base64-encodes it. If you want to be 100% sure, test it.

Comment: Did you find how to manage this?